# WF4 RC - Cannot create unknown type when loading WF Service from loose Xaml with ActivityXamlServices

Tags: xaml, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to host a WF4 (RC) Service dynamically. I have a test solution with two projects. The first is a declarative workflow service library with one root Flowchart activity in it, and a simple custom code activity. The workflow service library does not depend on any other custom assemblies or references. The second is my host app, which in my test solution is just a console application.

In my host app, I am attempting to the use ActivityXamlServices to load the Xaml for the workflow service into an activity, and then use the WorkflowServiceHost to fire up a workflow instance using that activity.

As soon as I try to new up the WorkflowServiceHost object, I get this exception...

> Cannot create unknown type
>   '{clr-namespace:DeclarativeServiceLibrary1}CodeActivity1'.

If I remove CodeActivity1 from my Flowchart designer, everything runs fine. If I add a direct reference to the workflow service project from my host project and then create a WorkflowServiceHost using an instance of my Flowchart activity instead of the activity created from the Xaml, it also works fine.

It seems to not like using my CodeActivity for some reason when loaded dynamically.

Anyone have any ideas as to why I can't dynamically create my workflow service?

My code is as follows...

DeclarativeServiceLibrary1.Activity1.xaml...

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="DeclarativeServiceLibrary1.Activity1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="654,676" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeclarativeServiceLibrary1" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/servicemodel" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System" xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Flowchart sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="C:\dev\test\MyWorkflow\DeclarativeServiceLibrary1\Activity1.xaml" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="614,636">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">False</x:Boolean>
        <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">270,2.5</av:Point>
        <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">60,75</av:Size>
        <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">300,77.5 300,107.5 300,165</av:PointCollection>
      </scg3:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <Flowchart.StartNode>
      <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID0">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">172.5,165</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">255,90</av:Size>
            <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">300,255 300,285 300,299.5</av:PointCollection>
          </scg3:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <p:Receive CanCreateInstance="True" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="255,90" OperationName="MyOperation" ServiceContractName="MyContractName" />
        <FlowStep.Next>
          <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID1">
            <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
              <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">194.5,299.5</av:Point>
                <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">211,61</av:Size>
                <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">300,360.5 300,390.5 300,399</av:PointCollection>
              </scg3:Dictionary>
            </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
            <WriteLine sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="211,61" Text="Workflow started" />
            <FlowStep.Next>
              <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID3">
                <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                  <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                    <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">200,399</av:Point>
                    <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,22</av:Size>
                    <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">300,421 300,451 300,479.5</av:PointCollection>
                  </scg3:Dictionary>
                </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                <local:CodeActivity1 sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" />
                <FlowStep.Next>
                  <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID2">
                    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                      <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                        <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">194.5,479.5</av:Point>
                        <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">211,61</av:Size>
                      </scg3:Dictionary>
                    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                    <WriteLine sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="211,61" Text="The code activity worked!" />
                  </FlowStep>
                </FlowStep.Next>
              </FlowStep>
            </FlowStep.Next>
          </FlowStep>
        </FlowStep.Next>
      </FlowStep>
    </Flowchart.StartNode>
    <x:Reference>__ReferenceID0</x:Reference>
    <x:Reference>__ReferenceID1</x:Reference>
    <x:Reference>__ReferenceID2</x:Reference>
    <x:Reference>__ReferenceID3</x:Reference>
  </Flowchart>
</Activity>
```

DeclarativeServiceLibrary1.CodeActivity1.cs ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Activities;

namespace DeclarativeServiceLibrary1
{

    public sealed class CodeActivity1 : CodeActivity
    {
        // Define an activity input argument of type string
        //public InArgument<string> Text { get; set; }

        // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
        // and return the value from the Execute method.
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument
            //string text = context.GetValue(this.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

DeclarativeServiceLibrary1.Web.Config ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

ConsoleApplication1.Program.cs ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.XamlIntegration;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activities;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Xaml;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            string baseAddress = @"http://localhost:8081/MyContractName";

            string curDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string wfDefPath =  Path.Combine(curDir, "Activity1.xaml");

            Activity workflowActivity = (Activity)ActivityXamlServices.Load(wfDefPath); 
            WorkflowService service = new WorkflowService { Body = workflowActivity }; 
            Uri serviceUri = new Uri(baseAddress, UriKind.Absolute); 
            WorkflowServiceHost host = new WorkflowServiceHost(service, new Uri[] { serviceUri }); 
            host.Open();

            //Display that we are listening on the console window
            Console.WriteLine("Workflow '{0}' is listening at '{1}'", host.Activity.DisplayName, baseAddress);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a post-build event in the delarative workflow service library that copies the Assembly and Xaml file into the bin\debug\ folder of the host console app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer - Xaml load can't infer the local (default) assembly, so you need to specify it on XamlReaderSettings.LocalAssembly.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I switched to using a XamlXmlReader to read in the xaml file using the XamlXmlReaderSettings.LocalAssembly as you described. Doing that and passing the XamlXmlReader into the ActivityXamlServices.Load method worked like a charm.

Comment: Alternatively you can split up the XAML workflows and the activities they use. When you do that, the activity isn't in the local CLR namespace anymore and will be loaded just fine. So just create a XAML workflow-only project and an Activity project.

Answer (score 9):

Open source code of the activity.
Change "xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeclarativeServiceLibrary1" to
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeclarativeServiceLibrary1;assembly=DeclarativeServiceLibrary1".

Comment: this also fixed another bug for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743133/solution-for-xamlinjectorcannot-create-unknown-type-errors-does-not-work

error: error "'Unexpected 'PROPERTYELEMENT' in parse rule 'Element ::= . EmptyElement | ( StartElement ElementBody ).'.'

Answer (score 0):

You're deserializing the xaml file directly, but it is referencing a type (CodeActivity1) that is compiled as a CLR type into the DeclarativeServiceLibrary1 assembly.  The most obvious answer is that the DeclarativeServiceLibrary1 assembly is not available to the console app at runtime.  Make sure that this assembly is copied into the folder where you are running the console app (\bin\debug) and see if that makes a difference.

The bottom line is that even though you are reading the xaml file directly, it still needs access to any types that it references.

Comment: The DeclarativeServiceLibrary1 assembly is copied over to the bin\debug\ folder of the console app. I even tried adding a direct reference to it from the console app.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code I can tell that you should have loaded a WorkflowService instead of a simple activity. There are basically two options to try here:

**Option 1: Load the activity and host it inside a generated workflow service.**

You can do this by loading the activity as normal and use the following snippet to make it into a workflow service instance:

```
WorkflowService service = new WorkflowService();
service.Body = loadedActivity;
```

After that you can host it inside the workflow service host.

**Option 2: Load the workflow service directly**

The second option is not much different from what you have now. But instead of using the ActivityXamlServices class you will need to use the XamlServices class to load the workflow service. After that it's a matter of firing up the workflow service host with the settings you used in your sample.

Comment: Option 1 works if I instantiate DeclarativeServiceLibrary1.Activity1 directly and use it, but it still doesn't like me loading up the Xaml from disk. I get my original error when trying to create the WorkflowServiceHost.

Option 2 gives me an error that says "'No matching constructor found on type 'System.Activities.Activity'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.'" as soon as I try to load up the activity using the XamlServices.Load method.

Let me know if you take a look at my updated code and I wil post it.

Comment: I've double checked my solution and I cannot reproduce the errors you are getting. I tried the following snippet of code:

Activity workflowActivity = (Activity)ActivityXamlServices.Load("Workflow1.xaml");
WorkflowService service = new WorkflowService
{
    Body = workflowActivity
};

Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost:9001/testservice",UriKind.Absolute);

WorkflowServiceHost host = new WorkflowServiceHost(service, new Uri[] { serviceUri });
host.Open();

Comment: I integrated in your code snipped and still can't seem to get it going for some reason. I updated the code in the post above. I also uploaded my whole solution to http://dntest.criticaltech.com/MyWorkflow.zip. Check it out if you get a chance. Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: After some careful evaluation of the situation I think I found the problem. This error seems to happen if you build a workflow that uses a CodeActivity or NativeActivity from the same assembly. Let me check some more things and I will get back to you.