# Solution for "XamlInjector–Cannot create unknown type errors" does not work

Tags: unit-testing, workflow-foundation-4

In unit test, i passed the assembly of Custom Activity to the ctor as the local assembly
 **var xamlInjector = new XamlInjector("CreditAtRenewalFlow.xaml", typeof(CreateFollowUp).Assembly);**

**CreateFollowUp is a AsynCodeActivity**

I got error "'Unexpected 'PROPERTYELEMENT' in parse rule 'Element ::= . EmptyElement | ( StartElement ElementBody ).'.' Line number '2' and line position '4'." at execution of the following line

**var host = WorkflowInvokerTest.Create(xamlInjector.GetActivity());**

> The sample of the unit test is    [TestMethod]
>          [DeploymentItem(@"src\ProcessFlows\Activity1.xaml")]
>          public void Activity1Test()
>          {
>
> ```
>     var xamlInjector = new XamlInjector("Activity1.xaml", typeof(CreateFollowUp).Assembly);
>     xamlInjector.ReplaceAll(typeof(CreateFollowUp), typeof (MockCreateFollowUp));
>
>     var mockExternalServiceManager = new Mock<IExternalServices>();
>     mockExternalServiceManager.Setup(x => x.CreateFollowUp()).Verifiable();
>
>     var host = WorkflowInvokerTest.Create(xamlInjector.GetActivity());
>
>     dynamic parameterValues1 = new WorkflowArguments();
>     parameterValues1.value1 = mockExternalServiceManager.Object;
>
>     IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = host.TestActivity();
>
>    }
> ```

And the CreateFollowUp is given below

> public sealed class CreateFollowUp : AsyncCodeActivity
>       {
>           [RequiredArgument]
>           public InArgument ExternalServices { get; set; }
>
> ```
>     protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, AsyncCallback callback,
> ```
>
> object state)
>           {
>               Action createFollowUp = this.ExternalServices.Get(context).CreateFollowUp;
>               context.UserState = createFollowUp;
>               return createFollowUp.BeginInvoke(callback, state);
>           }
>
> ```
>     protected override void EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
>     {
>         var createFollowUp = context.UserState as Action;
>         if (createFollowUp == null)
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentNullException("The AsyncState of the IAsyncResult was not of the type
> ```
>
> ExternalServices.AsyncCreateFollowUp.", (Exception)null);
>               }
>
> ```
>         createFollowUp.EndInvoke(result);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: interesting... never seen that before.  Would you mind sending your XAML to me?  ron (dot) jacobs (at) microsoft (dot) com

Comment: Sorry for replyling back late, after reving my code again I realised that WorkflowArguments was giving problem. So when I changed input argumenst as dictionary object it worked fine.

Comment: In your case, how did you fix it? Why do you need to change input arg into dictionary object? I have same issue here, and I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try to modify source code of the activity. Change "xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Activity1" to xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Activity1;assembly=Activity1".

include the assembly in namespaces references (use the correct assembly name)