# Dynamic sqlWorkflowInstanceStore

Tags: persistence, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice, sqlworkflowpersistencese

I have created an application using this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff646977.aspx

What i need to do is callWorkflow instances store dynamically
i.e  before

```
string message = "";        
string result = client.EvaluateMortgage();
```

I should be able to specify the sqlworkflowinstancestore i.e where the workflow data is

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `callWorkflow instances store dynamically` ?

Comment: I have to dynamically specify the connection string for sqlWorkflowInstanceStore , I dont want this in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this,

```
 SqlWorkflowInstanceStore store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(connectionString);
```

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.durableinstancing.sqlworkflowinstancestore.aspx)

[Here you can find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395773.aspx) several ways of configuring /using it

Comment: But where :) in service or app and how .

Comment: using (System.ServiceModel.Activities.WorkflowServiceHost host = new System.ServiceModel.Activities.WorkflowServiceHost(XamlServices.Load(ActivityXamlServices.CreateReader(new XamlXmlReader(path, new XamlXmlReaderSettings { LocalAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ServiceReference1.test)) }))), serviceAddress.Uri))         {SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreBehavior());
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreBehavior
                {ConnectionString = "connecting string" });                host.Open();

}

Comment: I did not want connection string in WF service that was my issue my client will decide the workflow, so the trick was to load the xaml file rather than using any reference. and when I load the xaml  can decide which connection string I have to use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330762/wf4-rc-cannot-create-unknown-type-when-loading-wf-service-from-loose-xaml-with  This helped me to find my way