# I cannot start an XAMLX workflow via IIS

Tags: iis, workflow-foundation-4

I am writing a WF 4 service.  I can run it out of Visual Studio 2013 just fine but when I try otherwise, (e.g. via a browser) I am getting

> [XamlObjectWriterException: 'Cannot create unknown type '{......

The  type it cannot create is one from a second, deployed assembly.   The second assembly **is mentioned in the namespace line in the .xamlx file** and that assembly is deployed.  However, IIS still cannot find it.

I have tried many strategies to resolve this but nothing budges the problem.  So, how can I get the IIS XAMLX handler to discover a type in the non-default assembly?

---

**Note**:  I understand that this question is very much like 
[WF4 RC - Cannot create unknown type when loading WF Service from loose Xaml with ActivityXamlServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330762/wf4-rc-cannot-create-unknown-type-when-loading-wf-service-from-loose-xaml-with)
but in that case, the assembly was **not** named in the namespace definition within .xamlx and the poser of the question was manually creating a WF instance.  In my case, the alternate assembly is named and deployed.   The WF instance is supposed to be created directly by the WF infrastructure which reads the xamlx file.

Comment: I have since discovered the problem:  it was my own--a case-sensitivity problem in a namespace.   Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since discovered the problem: it was my own--a case-sensitivity problem in a namespace caused the other class to not be found.  Fixing the namespace casing fixed the issue.